# RegExp: как между парами повторяющихся символов извлечь текст?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, autohotkey

Имеется строка вида `<kuku>FF<dudu><mumu>GG<tutu>`. Нужно извлечь все, что встречается между ><. Выражение `(?<=>)(.+?)(?=<)` извлекает первую подстроку - FF. Как сие повторить для последующих вхождений?

Comment: Добавить модификатор /g.

Comment: Повтор осуществляется обычно внешними средствами: флагом глобального поиска (обычно g), или циклом и т.п. зависит от языка которым вы пользуетесь.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли в понимании происходящего. Проверял вот здесь: https://regex101.com/r/iD0pF6/2. Никак не мог понять, куда этот модификатор добавить. Потом дошло. Генератор кода также очень полезен, но проблема в том, что Autohotkey, судя по всему, не поддерживает глобальный модификатор ;)

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/14817-grep-global-regular-expression-match/ или гуглите https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=autohotkey+regex+flag+global там есть полезные ссылки.